# node.js sending input to stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm trying to launch the [plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.65/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) binary using the child_process module for node.

The process spawns fine, however I cannot seem to send input to it, as it does receive the `"n \n"` command that the script sends.
The strange thing is that it works fine with CMD ([screenshot](http://puu.sh/jL7uj/8b6edeaafe.png)). As such, I am wondering if the process blocks automated input?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var server = {
  ipAddress: "",
  username: "",
  password: "",
  port: "22"
};

var fwdport = "1234";

 var spawnArgs = [ 
                    '-ssh',
                    server.username + '@' + server.ipAddress,
                    '-pw',
                    server.password,
                    '-C',
                    '-T',
                    '-P',
                    server.port,
                    '-D',
                    '127.0.0.1:' +fwdport, 
                    '-N' ];

var ssh = spawn('plink.exe', spawnArgs, {
  env: process.env
});



ssh.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ssh.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ssh.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    ssh.stdin.write("n \n");
    console.log("sent");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Your code shows you spawning `cmd` instead of `plink`, is that a typo?

Comment: yep, it was from when I tested it with CMD. Fixed.

Comment: Perhaps it's looking for CRLF instead of just LF? Did you try `\r\n`?

Comment: Nope,  same problem ([screenshot](http://puu.sh/jL9kk/1a084b2d70.png)). Looks like [this](http://puu.sh/jL9mV/38f9ba75a8.png) when it's done via CMD

Comment: Tried the ASCII code as well (\x0A) but still no luck.

Comment: Maybe 3 seconds isn't enough time to spawn the process and make the connection? Try sending the response when you see the prompt in the stdout event handler.

Comment: I tried that as well, but no luck. I tested just the "\n" string and it works (aborts the process). Very strange.

Comment: You also tried without the space between the `n` and `\n`?

Comment: Yep, did not make a difference. Enter any characters then pressing enter when using it via CMD provides the correct result (connection success), so it does not have to be the letter n.